# Django URL regex not working

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have a Django URL I can't seem to get to work.  I'm thinking it's something Django related rather than the regex itself since the regex is working at pythex.org.

Here's the URL string:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/invitation.html?S2XEvent=ConfirmInvitation&Type=Participant&ValidationKey=ab8a8f1fc1927044feb89245dd88a55e&InvitationId=14708
```

And here's the line in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^invitation\.html\?S2XEvent=ConfirmInvitation&Type=(?P<invitation_type>\w+)&ValidationKey=(?P<validation_key>\w+)&InvitationId=(?P<invitation_id>\d+)$', 'events.views.accept'),
```

Before anyone yells at me about the ugly URL, this is just for legacy purposes as this code is replacing an existing application.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if you're supposed to write out query params in url configuration. Prolly messing it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how Django urls work. Query parameters - those after the `?` - are not part of the urlpattern but are captured in `request.GET`.

Your pattern should just be `r'^invitation\.html$'`.

Comment: Alright that makes sense.
So I just need to send all invitation.html requests to whatever view, then get them from request.GET?